# Laravel 5.4 UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 444 in form submition

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am making multiauth. When I submit admin email and password from admin login view I got bellow error 
"UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 444:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given."
here is my form

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Admin Login</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('admin.login.submit') }}">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                        <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Login
                                    </button>

                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        Forgot Your Password?
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

And here is route

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function (){
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
});
```

And the controller is here

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.login');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What wrong here?
And How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that problem. that was in my controller. Exactly in login function. I returened true. Here is the problem. When I return 1 then it worked.